# Align previous and next list items above and below active item

Tags: jquery, html, css, position

I have a fixed vertical (ul) list (100% screen height) and I'm trying to have one active item and the previous items display above and next items display below. I'm not sure if this is possible, though. Any thoughts or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Can you show what you have accomplished so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the list to `display: flex; flex-direction: column;`, then set the active element to `flex-grow: 1; display: flex; align-items: center;` to have that element grow to take up all of the available space, then center it's contents in the middle.

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0}
ul {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
}
.active {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li class="active">foo</li>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>foo</li>
</ul>
```